# how to make images same size?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I try to render in mages in Angular, using ng-repeat
But every image has it's own size(some round , some oval), despite that I've set size in DOM element.

```
<div ng-repeat="member in vm.members" class="memberList" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
     {{member.username}}
     <img class="md-avatar" style="border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid black" height="60" width="60" src={{member.user_picture}}>
</div>
```

how to make all rendered images same height and width?

Comment: There are no round or oval images. If their aspect ratio doesn't match to be 1:1 by setting width as well as height you're forcing it to use that width/height and the aspect ratio of the image will be wrong. if you only set either or use CSS for the sizing (using max-width/max-height) the aspect ratio should be retained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to your style of the img tag :

```
<img class="md-avatar" style="border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid black;height:60px!important;width:60px!important;" ng-src="member.user_picture" />
```

Comment: My pleasure. Also dont forget to mark this answer as correct  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try This.. :)

```
<div ng-repeat="member in vm.members" class="memberList" layout="column" layout-align="start center">
      {{member.username}}
      <img class="md-avatar" style="border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid black;width:60px;height:60px"  src={{member.user_picture}}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `height` & `width` properties inside the `style` attribute.

```
<div ng-repeat="member in vm.members" class="memberList" layout="column"
     layout-align="start center"> {{member.username}}
     <img class="md-avatar" style="border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid black; height: 60px; width: 60px;"  src={{member.user_picture}}>
</div>
```